# Identify the "s between '<' and '>' which are not preceeded by '=' and not followed by a space

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var str = '<img src="logo.gif"align="left">';
```

Need to get the 2nd " ( which is not followed by a space) in JavaScript.
Any regex for this?

Comment: example:
var str = '<img src="logo.gif"align="left">;

Comment: Need to get the 2nd " ( which is not followed by a space) in JavaScript. Any regex for this?

Comment: show the value that should be matched

Comment: This makes me curious about which problem you're solving.

Comment: Okay, what did you try and what went wrong? What problem are you trying to solve?  Must you use regular expressions, or is a (possibly rather more) sane DOM approach allowed? And the `align` attribute is deprecated, use CSS to style and present your content.

Comment: Need to replace '<img src="logo.gif"align="left">' (missing space before align) with '<img src="logo.gif" align="left">' (added space before align) in JavaScript. This should reflect with any html tag with similar pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `match()` method with the following regex to see if there is such a `"`

```
'<img src="logo.gif"align="left">'.match(/="[^"]+(")[^>\s]/)
```

If there is an offending `"`, the above will return an **array with length 2**.

If there isn't, it will return `null`.